# Files won't get deleted from workspace while cleaning up

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins-plugins

I have the following error and the jenkins is unable to remove some files from the workspace. I can manually remove the file but how can I make it automated? I checked delete workspace before building and inserted **/tellar.tar.gz in "patterns of the file to delete and include" but still wouldn't do it.

Deleting project workspace...

Cleaning local Directory .

hudson.util.IOException2: remote file operation failed: /local/hudson/workspace/CITI_PATCH_LATE at hudson.remoting.Channel@bac49a:usnjapp09.mh.lucent.com
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:848)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:825)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:743)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:685)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1325)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:682)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:88)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:587)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1543)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:236)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to delete /local/hudson/workspace/CITI_PATCH_LATE/./CITI/citi_patch_ll151_rctm/check/tellar.tar.gz
    at hudson.Util.deleteFile(Util.java:243)
    at hudson.Util.deleteRecursive(Util.java:293)
    at hudson.Util.deleteContentsRecursive(Util.java:204)
    at hudson.Util.deleteRecursive(Util.java:284)
    at hudson.Util.deleteContentsRecursive(Util.java:204)
    at hudson.Util.deleteRecursive(Util.java:284)
    at hudson.Util.deleteContentsRecursive(Util.java:204)
    at hudson.Util.deleteRecursive(Util.java:284)
    at hudson.Util.deleteContentsRecursive(Util.java:204)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.CheckoutUpdater$1.perform(CheckoutUpdater.java:71)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.WorkspaceUpdater$UpdateTask.delegateTo(WorkspaceUpdater.java:136)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.perform(SubversionSCM.java:788)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:769)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:753)
    at hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:2309)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Archiving artifacts

Answer (score 5):

I was facing the same issue, then I realized that my explorer was accessing the directory that *Jenkins* was trying to delete. After closing the explorer, the job succeeded.

So even you can try closing all application accessing the folder in your workspace.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps permissions. Can you delete with the slave user?
More common on windows, but sometimes a process has a lock on the file.